# Writing domain set for function F

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry

[image]

For this function, I plot it. And I show the areas where $F$ take positive and negative values on the graph.

Well, how can I write the set which shows the areas that F be positive and F be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the positive values:
$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geqslant |x|\}\bigcup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\leqslant -|x|\}$$
And for the negatives is practically the same.

Comment: Then, for negative values, $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : x\ge |y|\}\bigcup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 :.x \le - |y|\}$ Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: |y|<|x|\}$$
This oughta do it.